# Prove that sequence $S_N(a, n, d) = ±1 \pmod N$ if $N$ is prime.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

The polynomial Sequence $S_N(a, n, d)$ where $N$ is the nth term in the sequence (for any integers a, n, d) is defined the recurrence relation:

$S_N = a\cdot S_{N-1}+d$

$S_{N-1} = a\cdot S_{N-2}+d$

.........

starting with

$S_1 = n$

$S_2 = a*n+d$

$S_3 = a\cdot S_2 +d$

$S_4 = a\cdot S_3 +d$

with coefficient $a$, root $n$, increment $d$.

Prove that sequence $S_N(a, n, d) = ±1 \pmod N$ if $N$ is prime and $n = 1$.

I would be able to prove it if there was a simple form for $S_N$ besides the recurrence relations. Can anyone prove the case for these sequences, with the root $n = 1$. Is this the case for other roots $n ≠ 1$? Thanks for help.

For example, the sequence $S_N(2, 1, 1$) yeilds the Mersenne numbers, and can be easily proven that if $N$ is prime, then $S_N ( 2, 1, 1 )  =   1 \pmod N$.

Comment: This is not true in general. Consider $(a,n,d)=(3,1,6)$; $S_3$ is obviously divisible by 3 and is therefore $0\bmod3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We observe:
$$S_1=n$$
$$S_2=a\cdot n+d$$
$$S_3=a^2\cdot n+d\cdot a+d$$
$$S_4=a^3\cdot n+d\cdot a^2+d\cdot a$$
Claim: For $N>1$ 
$$S_N=a^{N-1}\cdot n+d\sum_{i=0}^{N-2}a^i$$ 
Proof by induction: 
$$S_2=a^1\cdot n+d\sum_{i=0}^{0}a^i$$
Assume that:
$$S_{N-1}=a^{N-2}\cdot n+ d\sum_{i=0}^{N-3}a^i$$
Now:
$$S_N=a\cdot S_{N-1}+d=a^{N-1}\cdot n+d\sum_{i=1}^{N-2}a^i+d=a^{N-1}\cdot n+d\sum_{i=0}^{N-2}a^i$$
So now that's done, we take $\sum_{i=0}^{N-2}a^i=\dfrac{a^{N-1}-1}{a-1}$ and plug it in:
$$S_N=a^{N-1}n+d\dfrac{a^{N-1}-1}{a-1}$$

---

Suppose $gcd(a,N)=1$. By Fermat's little theorem, if $N$ is prime:
$$S_N\equiv n+d\dfrac{1-1}{a-1}\equiv n\pmod N$$
therefore we can conclude that every sequence $S(a,n,d)$ contains at most $\omega(a)$ elements with prime index $p$, say $S_p$ such that $S_p\not\equiv n\pmod p$ (because the only primes $p$ with $gcd(a,p)\neq 1$ are the primes that divide $a$).

You simply had $n=1$ in your Mersenne sequence and that's why you got all those ones as residues.

EDIT:
we can make this bound even sharper, since for $N>1$, we have $S_N>a$ and hence $S_N\nmid a$. But $1$ isn't a prime, so $S_N(a,n,d)\equiv n \pmod N$ for all primes $N$.